# Why aren't the init and windowControllerDidLoadNib: method called when a autosaved document is automatically open ?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument, autosave

I have a `NS(Persistent)Document`.

I run my application via Xcode, then create a new document (without any data), and then quit my application.
In this case, I can check that the `init` and `windowControllerDidLoadNib:` are called

If I re-run my application with Xcode, then the previous document is automatically open.
But, I can check that neither `init` nor `windowControllerDidLoadNib:` are called.

Why is it so ?

Comment: Maybe because the `NSDocument` is "kind of stored somewhere" and thus does not have to be "re-created" via `init` methods, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're seeing is [window restoration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011179-CH5-SW8). As that document (part of the Document-Based App Programming Guide) puts it:

> The document architecture implements the following steps in the window restoration process; the steps correlate to the numbers shown in Figure 5-2:
>
> 1. The `NSWindowController` method `setDocument:` sets the restoration class of document windows to the class of the shared `NSDocumentController` object. The `NSWindow` object invalidates its restorable state whenever its state changes by sending `invalidateRestorableState` to itself.
> 2. At the next appropriate time, Cocoa sends the window [an `encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:` message](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:), and the window encodes identification and status information into the passed-in encoder.
> 3. When the system restarts, Cocoa relaunches the app and sends the `restoreWindowWithIdentifier:state:completionHandler:` message to the `NSApp` object.
>
>    Apps can override this method to do any general work needed for window restoration, such as substituting a new restoration class or loading it from a separate bundle.
>
>    `NSApp` decodes the restoration class for the window, sends [the `restoreWindowWithIdentifier:state:completionHandler:` message](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSWindowRestoration_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfcm/NSWindowRestoration/restoreWindowWithIdentifier:state:completionHandler:) to the restoration class object [in this case, the document controller's class —Peter], and returns `YES`.
> 4. The restoration class reopens the document and locates its window. Then it invokes the passed-in completion handler with the window as a parameter.
> 5. Cocoa sends [the `restoreStateWithCoder:` message](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/restoreStateWithCoder:) to the window, which decodes its restorable state from the passed-in `NSCoder` object and restores the details of its content.
>
> [Figure 5-2, and a paragraph explaining that views, other responders, and the document get saved and restored, too]
>
> When the app is relaunched, Cocoa sends the `restoreStateWithCoder:` message to the relevant objects in turn: first to the `NSApplication` object, then to each `NSWindow` object, then to the `NSWindowController` object, then to the `NSDocument` object, and then to each view that has saved state.

[The window restoration protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSWindowRestoration_protocol/) is used for non-document-related windows, too, but the document machinery handles most of the dirty work for you. If you need to do anything on either side (probably both sides) of window restoration, override `encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:` and `restoreStateWithCoder:` in your document. The former is where you save transient information like selections, and the latter is where you restore that information in the resurrected document and its window(s).

The presence of coders implies that the document is initialized using `initWithCoder:` rather than `init`, though this isn't a documented fact (in the context of window restoration) that you should rely upon.

Comment: In an `NSPersistentDocument`, when the application tries to load an unsaved but autosaved document, the message send to `NSPersistentDocument` is `restoreDocumentWindowWithIdentifier:state:completionHandler:`. It helps to override this method to prevent some bugs. Good to know !

Comment: @Colas: That's not specific to NSPersistentDocument; it's defined in NSDocument. Curious that the guide I quoted left it out…